# Save a Form as a Report using VBA

Tags: vba, forms, ms-access, report

In MS Access it's possible to convert a Form to a Report using the "Save Object As" functionality (Office Button -> Save As -> Save Object As "Save the current database object as a new object").

I'd like to have the same functionality using VBA but it seems to me that none of the following relevant DoCmd methods are suitable CopyObject, OutputTo, Save, TransferDatabase.

I was unable to find any useful information, except a [blog post](https://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/threads/save-form-as-report.52133/#post-200415) in which a code sample is provided using the SendKeys statement, but it seems not working.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to convert a form to a report using VBA. Even using Sendkeys (which really should be avoided as there is a potential for the wrong application to get the keypresses instead) is not an effective method, as some controls don't get converted correctly.

Instead, you should be designing a report from scratch, with the required headers/sorting/grouping - it will look far better.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to some tips from MajP on an access-programmers forum [post](https://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/threads/save-form-as-report-using-vba.312632/#post-1706029), I found a way that is suitable for my needs, although it uses the sendkey function:

```
strFormName = "formname"
strReportName = "reportname"

DoCmd.SelectObject acForm, strFormName, True

SendKeys strReportName & "~"

RunCommand acCmdSaveAsReport
```

strFormName must contain the name of the Form to be saved as a Report whose name must be contained in strReportName.